# Problema al registrar usuario con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy realizando un registro, a la hora de ingresar los datos en los input y registrarme, el programa siempre me da **Error**.

Esto se que es porque mi variable *resultadouser* queda igual a 0, Adjunto codigo para que vean de lo que hablo

```
    <?php
include ("connect.php");
//Registrar usuario
if (isset($_POST["registrar"])){
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['username']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['pass']);
$password_encriptada = sha1($password);
$sqluser = "SELECT idusuarios FROM user WHERE user = '$username' ";
$resultadouser = $connect->query($sqluser);
$filas = $resultadouser->num_rows;

if ($filas > 0) {
    echo "<script>
    alert('El usuario ya existe');
    window.location = 'index.php';
    </script>";
}else{
    $sqlusuario = "INSERT INTO usuarios(user,email,password,password_encriptada)
    VALUES ('$username', '$correo','$password','$password_encriptada')";
    $resultadouser = $connect->query($sqlusuario);
    if ($resultadouser > 0){
        echo "<script>
        alert('Registro Exitoso');
        window.location = 'index.php';
        </script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script>
        alert('Error');
        window.location = 'index.php';
        </script>";

    }
}
}
?>
```

Conexion a mysql:

```
    <?php
include("config.php"); //Es como un HREF, incluye las otras variables en config.php
$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$bd = "phplogin";

// Create connection
$connect = new mysqli($server, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($connect->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

**(El error no es de conexion)**

El error que me da luego de apretar en el boton de registrar:

[image: Error]

Si necesitan ver alguna otra parte del codigo, me avisan y yo actualizo enseguida, Toda ayuda es muy bien recibida, tambien criticas constructivas acerca de como estructuro el codigo (Estoy estudiando PHP hace una hora y media). Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: En tu insert después de password tienes una coma de más prueba quitando la

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, ya lo hice, sigue dando error

Comment: Seguimos a ciegas, edita y agrega el mensaje de error

Comment: El error es el alert('Error');

Esa parte del codigo esta casi al final, es el ultimo else

Comment: Si pero ese error no nos dice nada, debes manejarlo de mejor forma, que usas para conectarte mysqli o pdo?

Comment: Para conectarme al mysqli tengo un archivo que es connect.php. Ahi edito y lo pongo

Comment: No tengo error en la conexion @BetaM, tengo error al registrarme

Comment: Perdona me confundí de link es este https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.errno.php

Comment: tu insert esta mal INSERT INTO usuarios(username,email,password,) le pusiste coma y le falta $password_encriptada

Comment: Hola Jorge, ya lo corregi por el comentario de otro usuario, ahi actualizo el codigo con todos los cambios

Comment: Hay varias cosas que debes replantearte si quieres escribir programas robustos. Hay algo que yo llamo *programación pesimista*, y sólo quienes la aplican logran escribir programas sólidos. Tu tarea como programador no es mostrar que lindo es programar pensando que todo saldrá bien (*programación pesimista*). Es todo lo contrario, debes pensar que todo puede salir mal y que precisamente tu tarea es enfrentar la situación cuando eso ocurra. Si analizamos tu código, vemos que el mismo sale corriendo o se queda mudo ante algunos problemas. Al menos debes controlar: 1. Si hay conexión o no ...

Comment: ... Eso no deberías resolverlo con un simple `die`, sino devolviendo `null`  y verificando el estado de la conexión; 2. Si la(s) consultas son o no erróneas; 3. Si el INSERT ocurrió realmente, lo cual se verifica con `affected_rows`, no verificando el estado del resultado de la ejecución de la consulta. Por ejemplo, puede haber un error de clave duplicada que tampoco controlas en el código. Como ves, hay puntos muertos en tu código que no controlas y por eso tienes tanta dificultad en saber lo que está ocurriendo, porque programaste pensando que todo o casi todo es color de rosa...

Comment: ... pero no lo es y debes responder cuando no lo sea. Otro problema en tu código es la vulnerabilidad, con ese programa te pueden inyectar código dañino en la BD o en el sistema y deberías usar consultas preparadas. Otra deficiencia es la mezcla de PHP/Javascript. Son dos universos diferentes y deberías separar responsabilidades. Hoy día, para comunicar entre cliente y servidor se usa Ajax, de modo que no mezclas scripts de JS dentro del código de servidor. Pero ese es otro tema, que dejo caer por si quieres optimizar/mejorar tu programa.

Comment: @A.Cedano muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta, como aclare, estoy aprendiendo PHP hace ya dos horas, Pero aprendi nuevas palabras reservadas como die, null y affected_rows, Realmente se agradece demasiado

Comment: Te redactaré una respuesta con algunas recomendaciones...

Comment: Muchisimas gracias

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112303/discussion-between-a-cedano-and-hatori-hanso).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te interesa poner en práctica el estilo de *programación pesimista*, según he comentado en tu pregunta, propongo esto.

Primero, simplifica tu archivo de conexión. Además tienes un error ahí: **no estás seleccionando ninguna base de datos** (te faltaba el cuarto parámetro del constructor).

Lee los comentarios en el código donde explico ciertas cosas:

```
<?php
    include("config.php"); //Es como un HREF, incluye las otras variables en config.php
    $server = "localhost";
    $dbUser = "root";      #dbUser para evitar confusiones en los include
    $dbPassword = "";      #dbPassword
    $bd = "phplogin";
    
    // Create connection
    /*
        Si la conexión falla será nula, eso basta
        a condición de verificar antes de usarla
        además, no conviene mostrar mensajes de error internos de la BD
        que pueden ser explotados por los hackers
    */
    $connect = new mysqli($server, $dbUser, $dbPassword, $bd);
?>
```

Ahora, vamos a escribir un programa robusto, que lo controle absolutamente todo. He puesto comentarios en varias partes del código.

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST["registrar"])){
        /*
            a. ¿Quién dice que el $_POST tendrá datos?
               Nadie, por tanto, debes controlarlo
               aquí usaremos un ternario
        */
    
        $username = !empty($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : NULL;
        $email = !empty($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : NULL;
        $password = !empty($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : NULL;
            
        /*
            Controlar TODO significa TODO
            primer ejemplo de descontrol: 
            incluir un archivo sin saber si vas a necesitarlo
            Si observas, he traslado el include dentro de este if
            porque sólo aquí queda claro que necesitaremos la conexión
            Si los datos fueron postados realmente,
            vamos a trabajar con ellos...
            Incluimos la conexión
        */
        if ($username && $email && $password) {
            include ("connect.php");
            /*
                Dado que $connect será null si la conexión falla
                controlamos esa eventualidad in situ
            */
            
            if ($connect) {
                /*
                    a. Preferiría consultas preparadas a mysqli_real_escape_string
                       pero ese es otro tema...
            
                    b. En tu código hay mezcla de estilos:
                       procedural y orientado a objetos,
                       pasaremos todo a estilo orientado a objetos
                */
                $username=$connect->real_escape_string($username);
                
                $sqluser = "SELECT idusuarios FROM user WHERE user = '$username' ";
                $resultadouser = $connect->query($sqluser);
                /*
                    Ciertas variables se pueden evitar
                */
    
                if ($resultadouser && $resultadouser->num_rows > 0) {
                    /*
                        Usando variables de control reducimos código repetitivo
                    */
                    $msg="El usuario ya existe";
                } else {
                    /*
                        Convendría quizá usar password_hash
                    */
                    $password_encriptada = sha1($password);
                    $correo=$connect->real_escape_string($email);
                    $password=$connect->real_escape_string($password);
                    $sqlusuario = "INSERT INTO usuarios(user,email,password,password_encriptada)
                    VALUES ('$username', '$correo','$password','$password_encriptada')";
                    $resultadouser = $connect->query($sqlusuario);
                    /*
                        Verificamos estado de query y las filas afectadas
                    */
                    if ($resultadouser && $connect->affected_rows > 0){
                        $msg="Registro Exitoso";
                    } else {
                        $msg="Error de consulta INSERT";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $msg="Conexión nula";
            }
        } else {
            $msg="Error. Variables vacías";
        }
    } else {
        $msg="Error. No hay POST registrar";
    }
    /*
            El código es el mismo
            sólo cambia el contenido de $msg
        */
    echo "<script>
        alert($msg);
        window.location = 'index.php';
        </script>";
?>
```

Comment: Es increible el codigo que me pasaste, solo me queda agradecer y ponerme a estudiar las exorbitantes cantidad de palabras reservadas que utilizaste que ni sabia que existitan, muchisimas gracias Cedano, voy a ver si puedo hacer que funcione ya que me tira error en la linea 31 y te aviso si puedo registrarme

Answer (score 1):

Estas declarando la variable `$username`

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['username']);
```

Pero en tu consulta estas diciendo que el campo user es igual a `$user`, de donde salio `$user`?

```
 $sqluser = "SELECT idusuarios FROM user WHERE user = '$user' ";
```

Respuesta editada:

Tu en el codigo estas seleccionando la tabla user y buscando en el campo user, mas sin embargo cuando intentas insertar datos lo estas haciendo en la tabla usuarios y en el campo username

`$sqlusuario = "INSERT INTO usuarios(username,email,password,)`

En donde intentas hacer el registro? verifica el nombre de tus tablas

Edicion #2:

Por lo visto el codigo que tienes fue un copia y pega y no sabes para que sirve cada cosa a continuacion te dare el codigo "arreglado" y algunos tips, no soy experto pero se de esto:

````
  <?php
//Comprobe la conexion y no tiene errores
include ("connect.php");
//Registrar usuario
//Aqui solo estas validando si el usuario presiono el boton "registrar" 
//Me imagino que en tu formulario debes tener ```method="POST" ``` 
//Y en tu input debes tener ```type="submit" name="registrar" ```
if (isset($_POST["registrar"])){
//Sinceramente no se porque pones la variable connect aqui
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['username']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['pass']);
$password_encriptada = sha1($password);
//Según tu comentario tu taba se llama usuarios y tu campo user
//No se porque seleccionas a idusuarios si no los utilizas
//Cuando utilizas SELECT* FROM seguido viene el nombre de la tabla
$sqluser = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE user = '$username' ";
$resultadouser = $connect->query($sqluser);
$filas = $resultadouser->num_rows;

if ($filas > 0) {
    echo "<script>
    alert('El usuario ya existe');
    window.location = 'index.php';
    </script>";
}else{
//No entiendo para que necesitas guardar la clave y la clave encriptada pero alli lo dejo
//Estas declarando la variable $correo pero segun el codigo declaraste $email
    $sqlusuario = "INSERT INTO usuarios(user,email,password,password_encriptada)
    VALUES ('$username', '$correo','$password','$password_encriptada')";
    $resultadouser = $connect->query($sqlusuario);
    if ($resultadouser > 0){
        echo "<script>
        alert('Registro Exitoso');
        window.location = 'index.php';
        </script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script>
        alert('Error');
        window.location = 'index.php';
        </script>";

    }
}
}
?>
````

Comment: Hola ernesto, muchas gracias por la respuesta, ya corregi ese error, pero lamentablemente sigue dando error, Tenes alguna idea porque puede ser?

Comment: El mismo error?

Comment: Si @ernesto jimenez

Comment: Segun tu codigo tu tabla se llama user y tu campo donde guardas el nombre de los usuarios tambien se llama user, eso es correcto?

Comment: Mi tabla se llama **usuarios** y el campo donde guardo el nombre de los usuarios se llama **user**

Comment: Respuesta editada, por favor verifica lo anotado

Comment: muchas gracias por la observacion, ya lo corregi, el mensaje de error sigue saliendo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112301/discussion-between-ernesto-jimenez-and-hatori-hanso).

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta, segun editaste lo que te di pero no lo veo

Comment: estoy en el chat

Comment: Ve la edición #2

Comment: Hola ernesto, No es un copia y pega realmente, estoy viendo el curso en [udemy](https://www.udemy.com/course/login-con-php-jairo-galeas/) El cual carece de muchas explicaciones, por lo cual al terminar el capitulo 8 y con tantos problemas, decidi lanzarme por mi cuenta con la documentacion a mi lado